# Running external exe using flash CS4

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, adobe

I need to launch an external exe (written in C++) using Adobe Flash AS3.

I have tried using fscommand and placing external exe in a folder "fscommand", but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the AIR 2 SDK, using an AIR app with a trusted installer, but it is not possible with the standalone flash player.

Fortunately, it probably won't take much work to move your code over to AIR. :)